# Custom font React-Native, [Unhandled promise rejection: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: ExpoFontLoader]

Tags: javascript, react-native, fonts, expo

I'm trying to implement a custom font in my react-native app. I followed the documentation from expo but I get an error saying:

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: ExpoFontLoader]

node_modules/expo-font/build/Font.js:103:25 in _loadSingleFontAsync$
node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:45:44 in tryCatch
... 14 more stack frames from framework internals
```

Here is my code from `Login.js`

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button, TextInput } from 'react-native'
//import firebase and it's auth module
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';
import * as Font from 'expo-font';


export default class Login extends React.Component {

  constructor(){
    super()
    this.state={
      fontLoaded:false
    }
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    await Font.loadAsync({
      'play': require('../assets/fonts/PressStart2P-Regular.ttf'),
    });

    this.setState({ fontLoaded: true });
  }
```

```
render() {

      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
        {this.state.fontLoaded ? (
          <Text style={styles.title}>Login</Text>
          ) : null
        }
```

I never used the variable: `ExpoFontLoader` and I can't find other info about this error. The text login with the font is not showing and I can't find a way to do it... Anyone who can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by myself, for some reason when I installed expo it took version 7.0.0 from expo-font. This had to be version 8.0.0 so I installed the correct version and now it works!

Answer (score 0):

Check you're `.ttf` file path.

I found something similar to this error :
https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/4626#issuecomment-503138343

Comment: Thank you for responding and I checked my path but is correct!